# MediaPlayer audio playing stops when app enters in background (OREO)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-8.0-oreo, android-background, android-8.1-oreo

I have a manager class with an array of `MediaPlayer` instances which is the manager for playing audio on my app. Until now, it worked perfectly in background and keep playing the audio when the device is blocked.

Now, starting with Oreo devices, the audio playing stops. Is there an easy way of forcing the device to keep alive the MediaPlayer instance which is playing the audio? I mean a simple way without using services or without creating custom bars on the notification bar of the device, which are the options I found for now here in Stack Overflow. Probably must be a simpler way.

This is the code I used to play an audio until now:

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer =  new MediaPlayer();
AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = ApplicationContextProvider.getContext().getAssets().openFd(res.getUrl());
long start = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
long end = fileDescriptor.getLength();
mPlayer.setDataSource(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), start, end);
mPlayer.prepareAsync();
mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
});
mPlayer.setLooping(loop);
fileDescriptor.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use foreground Serive. For details on why the service will no longer work watch

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pumf_4yjTMc

It clearly says that background services will be stopped. For tutorial on Foreground Services watch:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbpD5RZtbCc

Remember you would also need to learn the notification channels starting Oreo. This guy has introduced that too.